# Experiment where are observations are chi square distributed

Tags: experiment-design, chi-squared-distribution, teaching

In order to introduce the chi-square-distribution I'd like to find a simple experiment where the measurements are chi-squared distributed.

Do you know a simple experiment where the measurement directly (or with minimal calculations) are chi-squared-distributed.

In a chi-squared hypothesis test one must explain tests, observed and expected values, the X^2-value etc before one can discuss the chi-squared value. This setup is somewhat involved, so that's the motivation for the question.

Comment: Most measurements cannot possibly have $\chi^2$ distributions, but they might be close to *constant multiples* of such distributions.  Since, therefore, it is apparent you are not concerned about such a multiple, you might as well think of $\chi^2$ as being a Gamma distribution: because it is.  You should have no trouble finding many situations modeled by Gamma distributions.

Comment: Good point - I'll look for data sets that are gamma distributed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Waiting times to the next decay event in radioactive decay should be well approximated by an exponential distribution and events are thought to be independent.

If the waiting times are expressed in multiples of the expected waiting time (which can be obtained from the half life) the waiting time to the $k$th event from now should be close to $\chi^2_{2k}$.

(The half life is $\ln(2)$ times the expected waiting time. Some half lives are known quite accurately.)

Comment: +1--but to be fully correct, you need to rescale the waiting times appropriately.

Comment: @whuber quite right; if the half-life is known this is straightforward. I'll edit